# HTTP forbids me to access to a specified resource when I authenticate correctly - JavaEE

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to develop a JavaEE 7.0 web application using NetBeans (IDE), GlassFish 4.1.0 (web server) and MySql 5.7.11 (Database server). My Operating System is Windows 8.1.

I would like to set up a very basic authentication system. The user enters a username and a password already inserted in the database and if it is correct, he will be able to access a webpage called index.jsp. 
Therefore, I proceeded in the following way in order to develop this authentication system:

1- **In the GlassFish admin console**, I went to the "**security/Realms/file**" window and add a username: "john" and a password:"azerty". The group list to which "john" belongs is called "cemsAdmin":

[image: Add a new user]

2- In the "security" general window, I enabled the **Default Principal To Role Mapping** option:
[image: Enable the Default Principal option]

3- In my NetBeans web app project I wrote the following code in the web.xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>JSP configuration for the admin console</description>
        <url-pattern>/admin/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>

    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>JSP configuration for the store front</description>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/admin/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/admin/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<resource-ref>
    <description>Connect to the cems database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/cems</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

3- In my NetBeans web app project I wrote the following code in the AdminServlet file:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdminServlet", urlPatterns = {"/admin/","/admin/logout"})

@ServletSecurity( @HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"cemsAdmin"}) )
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet {

private String userPath;

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    userPath = request.getServletPath();

    System.out.println("The user path is:"+userPath);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
    userPath = "/admin/index.jsp";
    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(userPath).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I run all the code I obtain the following webpage:

[image]

Therefore, I enter the username **"john"** and the password **"azerty"** and I have the following **HTTP error**:

[image: The HTTP error]

I really do not know what is going on. Could you help me please ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a security constraint in your web.xml.
Something like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>rr</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>RoleOne</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>RoleOne</role-name>
</security-role>
```

You also are missing security-role definition.

Comment: Hi Armando, thank you for your help. I've just applied your advice. However, it does not work. I've added a security constraint, an auth-constraint and a security role but it gives me the same HTTP forbidden error.

Comment: In the example I provided the url-pattern is not the one you are applying the constraint to. The pattern for your resource would be /admin/* Use * to make sure that the constraint is applied to every resouce in that folder, so to speak